# Is there a way in Django to expose only a certain range of URLs based on some predefined variable?

Tags: python, django, metadata, django-urls

I am basically trying to expose a a range of defined URLs in an application.

E.g., I have 10k x2 resources which I'm hosting at /metadata/type1_1 and /metadata/type2_1 where each resource grouping iterates up to type1_10000 and type2_10000 respectively (20,000 stored assets I intend to serve over a manually-driven interval).

As such, I'm trying to define a URL scheme such that

max_available_metadata = current_limit [e.g. this may be 300, 7777 etc.] and I only want to configure the URLs within the pattern up to this limit. e.g., if I sent it to 25, type1_1, type1_2...25 and likewise type2_1, type2_2... type2_25 would all map properly but attempting to go to metadata/type1_26 through type1_10000 would all return 404s, likewise for type 2.

I'll probably want to configure setting this via the django admin but this isn't part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control this in your view.

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "metadata/type<int:asset_type>_<int:asset_num>/",
        views.serve_asset,
    ),

# views.py
def serve_asset(request, asset_type, asset_num):
    if asset_type == 1:
        if asset_num <= MAX_ALLOWED_ASSET_NUM:
            # do your stuff for asset 1
    elif asset_type == 2:
        ...
    raise Http404("Asset not exist")
```